# Auto create not existing directory Spring Integration SFTP

Tags: spring-boot, spring-el, spring-integration-sftp

Currently i use this configuration for Spring Integration SFTP:

```
@Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toSftpChannel")
  public MessageHandler handler() {
    final SftpMessageHandler handler = new SftpMessageHandler(sftpSessionFactory());
    handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpressionString("\'" + properties.getFolder() + "\'"
        + ".concat(headers['region'])");
    handler.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
    return handler;
  }
```

And all works, but sometimes i get an exception

```
MessageDeliveryException: Failed to transfer file [/test/home-dir/feed.xml -> feed.xml] from local directory to remote directory.; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: failed to create remote directory '/test-sftp'.; nested exception is 4: 
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.doSend(RemoteFileTemplate.java:347)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.lambda$send$0(RemoteFileTemplate.java:298)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:437)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:298)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:286)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:278)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(FileTransferringMessageHandler.java:205)
```

The main problem, that i already have directory `/test-sftp`, and strange thing, that in `properties.getFolder() (application.properties)` i set `/test-sftp/dir/`, and but get an exception about half of the path. How it is possible? 
My goal is exclude this part of path from creation. Is it possible to create only dir from `headers['region']`.
Example. I have `/test-sftp/dir/` and need only create `/test-sftp/dir/one`
`/test-sftp/dir/two`. But if dir from `/test-sftp/dir/` not exists, then just fail.

P.S. I have all accesses and fail to upload file to SFTP only 5 from 100 times (all directories exists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show the entire stack trace; don't truncate stack traces here.

> but get an exception about half of the path.

SFTP doesn't support creating a directory tree in one step; we have to create them recursively. See `RemoteFileUtils.makeDirectories()`.

Comment: Thanks, Gary for your answers, yo helped me a lot with your tips, but this time problem was at customer side

Answer (score 0):

Solved. We used customers SFTP which have many firewalls. We have Caused By: Pipe Closed, so, seems like sftp close long running open sessions and spring integration sftp do not realize it fast. 
So, the solution was to delete CachingSessionFactory for the time. Now all works without any issues.